# How to execxute a Latex file?

Tags: latex, miktex, texmaker

everyone I'm trying to compile a latex file in Windows using MiKTeX and Texmaker. But the file is not compiling and there is showing an error as " Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Can anyone help in this regard as to how this file will execute?.

Comment: Probably texmaker can't find your miktex distribution. If you go to `Options -> Configure Texmaker` are the paths correctly set to your installation of miktex?

Comment: (if you are new to this, I suggest to not bother with texmaker. Instead have a look at texstudio. This is was originally a clone of texmaker, but got many more nice features in the mean time)